# EJB Schedule issue

Tags: jakarta-ee, timer, ejb

I have a cosmetic issue while configuring the schedule annotation on one of the methods in my stateless session bean.

```
@Schedule(minute = "*/5", hour = "*", persistent = false)
@Override
public void retrieveDoc() {
    try {

        //--- --- --- --- --- --- --- 
    } catch (InterruptedException ex) {

    }
}
```

I want my method to execute for every 5 minutes. However this execution stops after around 7 days. Is there something that I am missing? I want this method to run after every 5 minutes as long as the server is up and running.

Any hint on this is highly appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because this is ejb, it is by default transactional. In order to effectively catch the exception thrown, wrap the logic into a different ejb call specifically calling that method in a diffrent transaction.

```
@Stateless
public class MySchedules{

  @EJB
  private MyScheduleService scheduleService;

  @Schedule(minute="*/5", hour="*")
  public void scheduleMe() {
     try {
       //The logic here is that you cannot catch an exception 
       //thrown by the current transaction, but you sure can catch
       //an exception thrown by the next transaction started 
       //by the following call.
       scheduleService.doTransactionalSchedule();
     }catch(Exception ex) {//log me}
  }
}

@Stateless
@TransactionAttribute(REQUIRES_NEW)
public class MyScheduleService {

   public void doTransactionalSchedule() {
     //do something meaningful that can throw an exception.
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your timer should go off every five minutes forever. Is it possible you caught an exception in that method? If an exception is thrown inside a @Schedule method, that method will be called again after 5 seconds, and if that fails, the timer dies.

Comment: Hmmm... now I understand why it abruptly stops execution. Is there a way to keep the timer alive even if something fails in the @Schedule method? Anyway thanks for the response.

Comment: Yep, it's because of transactions. Try maress' solution.